# Common interface for various devices (web, smart tv, tablet, mobile)

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

We deliver content for different devices - web, smart tv, tablet and mobile - and I'm trying to provide a common JavaScript interface providing functions like play stream, alert, log etc without thinking of how the device actually do this.

My question is: Is there a way to provide this like an interface, that the Device could implement and ensure that all implementations follows this interface signature?

**Example of implementation of typical functions against web browser on pc:**

```
    $.extend({
        Device : function() {

            this.play = function(url){
                console.log("Play: " + url);
            }

            this.alert = function(title, message, buttonText) {
                alert(title + "\n" + message);
            }

            this.log = function(message){
                console.log(message);
            }

            this.error = function(message){
                console.error(message);
            }
        }
    });
```

**The same functions against against samsung tv**

```
$.extend({
    Device : function() {
        var that = this;

        var TV = new $.TV();
        TV.init();

        this.play = function(url){
            TV.play(url);
            that.log("Play: " + url);
        }

        this.alert = function(title, message, buttonText) {
            alert(title + "\n" + message);
        }

        this.log = function(message){
            //no console on tv, so have to include on in the html
            $("#console").append('<div class="console-log">' + message + '</div>');
            if($("#console").children().size()>=5){
                $("#console").children().first().remove();
            }
        }

        this.error = function(message){                
            $("#console").append('<div class="console-error">' + message + '</div>');
            if($("#console").children().size()>=5){
                $("#console").children().first().remove();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. They are called prototypes.

You use prototypical inheritance.

(Uses [`.new`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.new) and [`Object.make`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.make) because prototypes are a bit ugly otherwise)

```
// Device prototype
var Device = {
    play: function(url){
        console.log("Play: " + url);
    },
    alert: function(title, message, buttonText) {
        alert(title + "\n" + message);
    },
    log: function(message){
        console.log(message);
    },
    error: function(message){
        console.error(message);
    }
};

var TVDevice = Object.make(Device, {
    constructor: function () {
        this.TV = new $.TV();
        this.TV.init();
    },
    play: function (url) {
        Device.play.apply(this, arguments);
        this.TV.play(url);    
    },
    log: function (message) {
        //no console on tv, so have to include on in the html
        $("#console").append('<div class="console-log">' + message + '</div>');
        if($("#console").children().size()>=5){
            $("#console").children().first().remove();
        }
    },
    error: function(message){                
        $("#console").append('<div class="console-error">' + message + '</div>');
        if($("#console").children().size()>=5){
            $("#console").children().first().remove();
        }
    }
});

var tvDevice = TVDevice.new();
```